# Recover Gitlab Docker setup

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to recover a Gitlab backup. The setup was done using a Docker container. The used Gitlab version was `gitlab-ce:10.7.3-ce.0`. The backup I did regularly was from the folders:

- /etc/gitlab/
- /var/log/gitlab/
- /var/opt/gitlab/

To run the Gitlab Docker container I used this BASH command:

```
sudo docker run --detach \
                --hostname gitlab.exampledomain.com \
                --publish 8081:80 \
                --name gitlab \
                --restart always \
                --volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
                --volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
                --volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
                gitlab/gitlab-ce:10.7.3-ce.0
```

To create the backup I used the following commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Turn off Gitlab.
sudo docker stop gitlab

# Backup Gitlab to tars.
sudo docker run --name temp-gitlab-backup-os \
                -it \
                -v /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
                -v /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
                -v /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
                -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu:16.04 sh -c "tar -cvzf /backup/gitlab.tar.gz /etc/gitlab /var/log/gitlab /var/opt/gitlab"

# Delete temp container.
sudo docker rm temp-gitlab-backup-os

# Delete temp image.
sudo docker rmi ubuntu:16.04

# Turn on Gitlab.
sudo docker start gitlab
```

To import the backup to an empty Gitlab Docker container I used the following commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Turn off Gitlab.
sudo docker stop gitlab

# Import Gitlab backup.
sudo docker run --name temp-gitlab-backup-os \
                -it \
                -v /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
                -v /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
                -v /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
                -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu:16.04 sh -c "tar -xvzf /backup/gitlab.tar.gz"

# Delete temp container.
sudo docker rm temp-gitlab-backup-os

# Delete temp image.
sudo docker rmi ubuntu:16.04

# Turn on Gitlab.
sudo docker start gitlab
```

Now, I would like to access the system again. So I create the Gitlab Docker container and then unzip the backup in the mentioned three folders. If I then run the Gitlab Docker container, it keeps on shutting down and restarting endlessly, preventing me from any access. I have all my projects on this Gitlab Docker backup, and I really want to regain access.

- Is there any way I can find out the used Gitlab Docker container version from the mentioned backup folders to verify that it was run in fact with the version `gitlab-ce:10.7.3-ce.0`?
- Is there any way I can access my projects in the mentioned backup folders? The data is there, but currently I have no idea how to export my projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1

> Is there any way I can find out the used Gitlab Docker container version from the mentioned backup folders to verify that it was run in fact with the version gitlab-ce:10.7.3-ce.0?

Yes, you can use `docker logs <container name>` to show all the logs output from the container, and pipe it to `head` to show only the first 10 lines, this is the output from my container:

```
> docker logs gitlab-wiki | head
Thank you for using GitLab Docker Image!
Current version: gitlab-ce=10.7.3-ce.0
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start: line 37: /proc/sys/fs/file-max: Read-only file system

Configure GitLab for your system by editing /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file
And restart this container to reload settings.
To do it use docker exec:

  docker exec -it gitlab vim /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
  docker restart gitlab

write /dev/stdout: The pipe is being closed.
```

As you can see, the second line printed the gitlab version.

## 2

> Is there any way I can access my projects in the mentioned backup folders? The data is there, but currently I have no idea how to export my projects.

Yes, because you have backed up your data, you can clone your git repo without docker.

First, extract your backup file:

```
tar zxvf /backup/gitlab.tar.gz
```

All your repo should be located at:

```
var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/<namespace>/<repo>.git
```

But these repos are `bare repository`, you can't use them directly. You need clone it by following command:

```
git clone var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/foo/bar.git foobar
```

---

At last, I think you should follow the official documents, use `gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create` and `gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:restore` to backup & restore. Copy files directly is not a good idea.